# Enums in Rails without ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, enums, activemodel

I want to use enums with MongoMapper and rails 4.
I know there are gems out there ([enumerize](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize)) which adds this behaviour but it seems like a lot to add for a small feature.

What is the easiest way of creating an enum for an ActiveModel class?

Answer (score 0):

Using getters, setters and an array of constants this can be quickly achieved:

```
class Subscription
  include MongoMapper::Document
  ...

  key :status, Integer

  STATE = [:queued, :submitted, :processing, :payment_received, :fully_paid, :error]

  def status=(str)
    @status = STATE.index(str)
  end

  def status
    STATE[@status]
  end
end
```

You could even add checks for common queries, eg the error state may need to be checked more often than others and you can skip the symbol > integer conversion:

```
def errors?
  @status == 5
end
```